# How is an XML document stored in SQL (SQL:2003)?

Tags: sql, xml, standards, iso, sqlxml

#### SQL:2003

When storing XML data (e.g. using the XML data type) how does SQL store this data?

*Are separate columns used? Is it stored as a string-type blob? Is it stored as files? How does work with parsing? How is an update performed on XML in SQL?*

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/xml-data-type-and-columns-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I'm looking for the official SQL:2003 standard definition of how this should be implemented.

Comment: SQL standards do not define how the XML is stored on disk the storage is platform depend, SQL standards only defines which functions should be possible or how to define the XML type in SQL

Answer (score 0):

The XML datatype is not substantially different than any other datatype in SQL. It can be used in any place you would ordinarily use any SQL datatype. There are few limitations:

- XML types cannot convert to text or ntext data types.
- No data type other than one of the string types can be cast to XML.
- XML columns cannot be used in GROUP BY statements.
- Distributed partitioned views or materialized views cannot contain XML data types.
- Use of the sql_variant instances cannot include XML as a subtype.
- XML columns cannot be part of a primary or foreign key.
- XML columns cannot be designated as unique.
- Collation (COLLATE clause) cannot be used on XML columns.
- XML columns cannot participate in rules.

useful resource [xml sql](https://nhnashuablog.wordpress.com/2010/06/22/to-shred-or-not-to-shred-ii-the-wrath-of-xquery/)

Comment: Hello. I see that a lot of bullets points appear verbatim in this link: https://nhnashuablog.wordpress.com/2010/06/22/to-shred-or-not-to-shred-ii-the-wrath-of-xquery/. If you copied these, please mention the source and attribute the author. Note also, that in the link these restrictions/traits apply to SQL Server. The article does not mention anything about the SQL:2003 standard.

Comment: @TT They was just some notes that I took in my class, anyway it seems that what it was discussed in my lecture was taken from that link so I will edit my answer :)

Comment: @TT main point is that your answer does not related to the ISO/ANSI SQL standard where the sql tag is about..the sql tag does not mean "SQL Server"

Comment: yeah I know, he looks for sandard sql, but the truth is that there's not a standard sql, there are some dialects and more features are common to all these dialects, xml included, then is up to every dbms to specify how data are treated internally

Comment: *"he looks for sandard sql, but the truth is that there's not a standard sql"* matrix  i was expecting no spoon but jokes aside you sure about that? Search `"ISO/IEC 9075"` on Google and tell me what you find..

Comment: why hmmm? There are SQL feautures that are present in all sql language (mysql, oracle, postgresql...) but for example in mysql you can use alias in the where clause while in Oracle you cannot, trigger syntax is another example of differences between sql dialects, I mean there is a kind of standard but vendors do not follow it perfectly and introduce specific features creating sql dialects

Comment: indeed but there is a clear SQL standard out there which most database tends to comform to and yes they some vendors if not all invert there own SQL dialect on top off that official SQL standard....As this question is tagged sql we should not be discussing vendor products..